# VS2012 Table Adapter Syntax Error: Expecting identifier or quoted identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012, tableadapter

I am trying to add a table adapter to one of my datasets.  The dataset has oracle as its datasource.  When I put in the query (which works elsewhere) I get this error.  The query has left outer joins in it.  If i go to query builder, it then adds stuff like { oj to the query.  I knew there was an issue with previous visual studio versions, but I thought they were fixed.  How can I get this to work.

```
SELECT PERS.PERS_ID,
       PERS.PERS_LAST_NM,
       PERS.PERS_FIRST_NM,
       PERS.PERS_MIDDLE_INIT,
       PERS.PERS_MIDDLE_INIT,
       PERS.PERS_PREFERRED_NM,
       PERS.PERS_EMPLOYEE_NO,
       PERS.PERS_EMPLOYEE_TYP,
       PERS.PERS_STAT,
       PERS.PERS_LENT_CD                        AS PERS_ENTITY,
       PERS.PERS_TYP,
       PERS.PERS_MSTP_ID,
       PERS.PERS_BLDG_ID,
       PERS.PERS_TITLE_INIT,
       PERS.PERS_PERS_ID,
       PERS.PERS_COCC_ID,
       PERS.PERS_IORG_CD,
       PERS.PERS_CORPORATE_ID,
       CONCAT('(', CONCAT(PERS.PERS_PHONE_AREA_CD, CONCAT(')',CONCAT(PERS.PERS_PHONE_EXCH_NO,CONCAT('-',PERS.PERS_PHONE_EXTN_NO))))) AS PERS_PHONE_NO,
       UPPER(EMAIL.ELID_LONG_USERID)            AS EMPL_EMAIL,
       UPPER(USERID.ELID_USERID)                AS EMPL_USERID
FROM   CDAS.TDWHPERS PERS
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ELID_PERS_ID, 
                               ELID_LONG_USERID
                        FROM   CDAS.TDWHELID
                        WHERE  ( ELID_EICT_CD = '0010' )
                               AND ( ELID_OPEN_IND = 'Y' )) EMAIL
                    ON PERS.PERS_ID = EMAIL.ELID_PERS_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ELID_PERS_ID,
                               ELID_USERID
                        FROM   CDAS.TDWHELID TDWHELID_1
                        WHERE  ( ELID_EICT_CD = '9100' )
                               AND ( ELID_OPEN_IND = 'Y' )) USERID
                    ON PERS.PERS_ID = USERID.ELID_PERS_ID
WHERE  ( PERS.PERS_STAT <> 'INACTIVE' )
       AND ( PERS.PERS_STAT <> 'UNKNOWN' )
ORDER  BY PERS.PERS_LAST_NM
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas, I am stuck.